# pipe out of rule in make recipe?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have the following situation:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
rule-%: etc/$$*
    some other things
    here
    something-something -c "cat $< | envsubst | ..." \
        > $@
```

And I'd like to rewrite this rule, as it is a common pattern across n items, without getting clever:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
rule-%: etc/$$*
   some other things
   here
   make something-something-$< > $@

something-something-%:
   something-something -c "cat $* | envsubst | ..."
```

But I can't find any guarantees that this will work if, suppose, I call the outer rule, `rule-%` as a submake from a different directory (make, in my experience, sometimes prints directory position into the pipeline -- which can be suppressed by executing make silently, but I would never assume a user to know that).

Will this work in all cases? Alternatively, I know I can:

```
etc...
    make something-something arg1=... arg2=...

something-something:
    something-something -c "cat ${arg1} | envsubst | ..." > ${arg2}
```

But I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question, but: first you should never use raw `make` when invoking make recursively: you must always use the `$(MAKE)` variable.

Second, if you want the recursive make to not print directory info, or even to run silently, you can just add those options to the submake: it won't matter what options the person who invoked the outer make specified:

```
$(MAKE) -s --no-print-directory something-something-$< > $@
```

Comment: I would not force add neither `-s` nor `--no-print-directory`. This should be final user call whether s/he wants more or less verbose output. Hardcoding such options makes Makefile troubleshooting harder.

Comment: I think you're missing the point: the OP wants to invoke make to build something rather than building it directly, and they want only the output of the command run by make to be redirected to a file.  While I certainly agree that forcing silent mode is in general a bad idea, in this case they expressly do _NOT_ want the output of make to appear because it will corrupt the resulting output file that they generate.

Comment: I think the OP actually wants to call a different target from the same Makefile, which is probably an overkill anyway to do it this way. Even with those switches hardcoded it will still be unreliable, e.g. user can call `make --trace` and it will again generate additional output.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep your code [DRY](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you can just make use of a template, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
.SECONDEXPANSION:

define something
  bash -c "cat $(1) | envsubst"
endef

rule-%: etc/$$*
        $(call something,$<) > $@

another-rule-%: etc/$$*
        $(call something,$<) > $@
```

Output:

```
$ make rule-foo another-rule-foo rule-bar another-rule-bar
bash -c "cat etc/foo | envsubst" > rule-foo
bash -c "cat etc/foo | envsubst" > another-rule-foo
bash -c "cat etc/bar | envsubst" > rule-bar
bash -c "cat etc/bar | envsubst" > another-rule-bar
```